# Over utilization of yarn resources with spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hql, hadoop-yarn

I have EMR cluster with below configuration.

```
Data Nodes : 6
RAM per Node : 56 GB
Cores per Node: 32
Instance Type: M4*4xLarge
```

I am running below `spark-sql` to execute 5 hive scripts in parallel.

```
spark-sql --master yarn --num-executors 1 --executor-memory 20G --executor-cores 20 --driver-memory 4G -f hive1.hql & spark-sql --master yarn --num-executors 1 --executor-memory 20G --executor-cores 20 --driver-memory 4G -f hive2.hql & spark-sql --master yarn --num-executors 1 --executor-memory 20G --executor-cores 20 --driver-memory 4G -f hive3.hql & spark-sql --master yarn --num-executors 1 --executor-memory 20G --executor-cores 20 --driver-memory 4G -f hive4.hql & spark-sql --master yarn --num-executors 1 --executor-memory 20G --executor-cores 20 --driver-memory 4G -f hive5.hql
```

But, **270 GB** of memory is being utilized by yarn.

As per the parameters in given command,

Each spark job should utilize only 120 GB RAM.

**1*20+4 = 24 GB RAM**

**5 jobs = 5 * 24 = 120 GB**

But, why yarn is utilizing 270 GB RAM? (No other Hadoop jobs are running in the cluster)

Do I need to include any extra parameters to limit yarn resource utilization?

Comment: Are you using EMR  setting : maximizeResourceAllocation true for this cluster ? It will be used by default if you launch it from console.

Comment: Yes. Dynamic resouce allocation is true for this cluster by default. Changing it to false resolved my issue. Please look into the answer section for more explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Make it as "spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled" false at spark-defaults.conf (../../spark/spark-x.x.x/conf/spark-defaults.conf)

This should help you limiting/avoiding dynamic allocation of resources.

Answer (score 0):

Even though we set executor memory in the command, spark allocates memory dynamically if resources are available in the cluster. To restrict the memory usage to only executor memory, spark dynamic memory allocation parameter should set to false.

You can change it directly in spark config file or pass as config parameter to the command.

```
spark-sql --master yarn --num-executors 1 --executor-memory 20G --executor-cores 20 --driver-memory 4G --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=false -f hive1.hql
```

Comment: Obviously. This is the expected behavior if it is enabled.

Spark provides a mechanism to dynamically adjust the resources your application occupies based on the workload. This means that your application may give resources back to the cluster if they are no longer used and request them again later when there is demand. This feature is particularly useful if multiple applications share resources in your Spark cluster.